# Prove n is a perfect square if and only if $n^7$ is a perfect square, n $\in$ natural numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, square-numbers

Proving one way is very simple

If n is a perfect square then

n = $a^2$

$n^7$ = $a^{14}$

$n^7$ = $a^7$($a^7$) which is obviously a perfect square for some integer a.

It's the if $n^7$ is a perfect square then n is a perfect square part that is giving me trouble. I have already tried to get hints from others and the one hint I was given was to write $n^7$ as a product of primes, but I have no clue where to go from there. I believe it can be done using modulus but I honestly have no idea.

Any hints would help thanks.

Comment: This is entirely uniqueness of the prime factorization. What can be said about the exponents in the prime factorization of a square?

Comment: By the linked post $\large \, n^7 = a^2\,\Rightarrow\, n = b^2,\ a = b^7\,$ for $\large \,b\in\Bbb Z\ \ \ $

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is helpful to observe that $n^6$ is a perfect square and $n=\frac{n^7}{n^6}$.

Comment: To reduce it to showing that if a whole number has a rational square root then it must be a perfect square?

Comment: @JonasMeyer It might be sufficient to show that if $a$ divides $b$ and both of them are squares, then their quotient is also a square.

Comment: Is that any different? If $n = (\frac{x}{y})^2$, then $y^2$ divides $x^2$.

Comment: @Jonas The hint is actually special case of various proofs in the linked dupe. It is clearer in *additive* form, viz. $ $if $\,2\mid 7n\,$ then $\,2\mid 6n\,\Rightarrow\, 2\mid n = 7n-6n.\ $ One of my answers in the dupe compares the multiplicative and additive forms.